# Why is pip install missing source of my package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, devpi

I have a private package which I have uploaded to my private devpi server. When I use pip to install it, only the egg folder is installed. The source is missing and hence I am unable to use any code or libraries in my package.

My `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
  name='my-package',
  version=1.0,
  packages=find_packages(),
  install_requires=[
      'requests>=2.21.0',
  ]
)
```

I am using a venv within Pycharm to do all of this. Why is this happening? How can I force pip to download and install the source distribution?

**[EDIT]**
When I download the tarball from my devpi server UI, it does NOT contain the source. Which means that when I upload the package with `devpi upload` it is not uploading the sdist? I could not find anything on how to force devpi to force to upload an sdist.

Here is the build log:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing ****.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to ****.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to ****.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to ****.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file '****.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file '****.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
warning: Check: missing required meta-data: url

warning: Check: missing meta-data: either (author and author_email) or (maintainer and maintainer_email) must be supplied

creating ...
creating ***.egg-info
creating ***-1.0/client
creating ***-1.0/client/model
copying files to ***-1.0...
copying README.md -> ****-1.0
copying setup.py -> ****-1.0
copying ****.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> ****-1.0/****.egg-info
copying ****.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> ****-1.0/****.egg-info
copying ****.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> ****-1.0/****.egg-info
copying ****.egg-info/requires.txt -> ****-1.0/****.egg-info
copying ****.egg-info/top_level.txt -> ****-1.0/****.egg-info
copying the actual source here
Writing ****-1.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing '****-1.0' (and everything under it)
```

Comment: What does `python -c "from setuptools import find_packages; print(find_packages())` output when executing it in the project root? Are all packages collected correctly?

Comment: Yes it seems to work fine - ['client', 'client.model']

Comment: Can you attach the complete build log? If the built egg/wheel contains all the sources, maybe you just need to reupload it.

Comment: added server logs

Comment: Now check whether the source dist contains the code, e.g. `tar tvf dist/pkg-ver.tar.gz`. If it's fine, reupload it via `devpi upload dist/pkg-ver.tar.gz`, verify the file was changed on server (by inspecting server log or checking in the web UI if you have `devpi-web` running) and try installing again. Check that you're using correct index and the index has `volatile=True` set if your upload will overwrite existing package version.

Comment: `devpi upload dist/pkg-ver.tar.gz` is what fixed it. Why won't the normal `devpi upload` from the root dir of my package achieve the same result?

Comment: Hard to say without an actual [mcve]; if you're not building in-place (so not issuing `devpi upload --no-vcs`), I'd tip on some config file not committed and thus not copied to build dir, but again, this is only a speculation. If you can extract the error to an mcve and add it to the question so I can reproduce it locally, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fixed it:

`devpi upload dist/pkg-ver.tar.gz`

Basically, run it from root of my project.